# factors of an equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to write a code which boils down to equation $(x y) = (x + y) N$.

My task is to find all the possible integer (natural number) solutions for $x$ and $y$. For example, say $N=6$. As $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers, $x+y$ is also a natural number, starting from $1,2,\ldots$ That is, the product $xy$ should meet the multiples of $6$.

Is there any easy way to find all the combinations of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Since you mentioned *programming*, is there an upper bound on $x, y$? i.e. a limit on how large $x$ and $y$ could be?

Comment: @ J.D. No sir no upper bounds

Comment: @ J.D. but they are natural numbers

Answer (score 5):

The equation can be rewritten as $(x-N)(y-N)=N^2$. So all positive solutions come from the factorizations  of $N^2$ as a product $uv$, and all such factorizations come from a solution. Just put $x=N+u$, $y=N+v$.

Thus the  problem of finding the solutions of your equation is essentially equivalent to the problem of finding all factors of  $N^2$, which is easily solved if we know all the factors of $N$.

However, for *very* large $N$, finding all the factors of $M$ can be computationally challenging.

**Remarks:** Let $N$ have prime power factorization $N=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$. Then the number of ordered pairs  $(u,v)$ of positive integers such that $uv=N^2$ is equal to $(2a_1+1)(2a_2+1)\cdots (2a_k+1)$. This is also the number of solutions of your equation. Thus you can manufacture examples where the number of solutions is large.

Comment: could you explain it with a simple example

Comment: Sure. Say $N=6$. Then $36=1\cdot 36=2\cdot 18=3\cdot 12$ and so on. Take for example $3\cdot 12$. Set $x-6=3$, $y-6=12$. That gives us the solution $x=9$, $y=18$.  For another example, $36=9\cdot 4$. So set $x-6=9$, $y-6=4$, we get the solution $x=15$, $y=10$.

Comment: sir could you explain it with an example

Comment: no sir the reason why it is difficult for large values

Comment: @cdummy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Comment: @André Nicolas k thanks.

Comment: By large I meant huge. There is no known fast algorithm for factoring. Of course factoring is easy by hand for numbers under a few hundred.  And we need only factor $N$, because from that we can pick up all factorizations of $N^2$.

Comment: Because of the symmetry, you can assume $v \ge u$.  Then if you want both solutions, you can switch them.  In André Nicolas' example, the factorization $3 \cdot 12=36$ gives $u=3=x-6, v=12=y-6$, giving (as he says) $x=9, y=18$.  You then also know there is a solution $x=18, y=9$